# Javascript in regexp not matching something

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match everything except the one with the string '1AB' in it. How do I do that? When I tried it, it said nothing is matched.

```
var text = "match1ABmatch match2ABmatch match3ABmatch";
var matches = text.match(/match(?!1AB)match/g);
console.log(matches[0]+"..."+matches[1]);
```

Comment: Downvoting for changing the question after answers were posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookarounds do not consume the text, i.e. the regex index does not move when their patterns are matched. See [*Lookarounds Stand their Ground*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground) for more details. You still must match the text with a consuming pattern, here, the digits.

Add `\w+` word matching pattern after the lookahead. NOTE: You may also use `\S+` if there can be any one or more non-whitespace chars. If there can be any chars, use `.+` (to match 1 or more chars other than line break chars) or `[^]+` (matches even line breaks).

```js
var text = "match100match match200match match300match";
var matches = text.match(/match(?!100(?!\d))\w+match/g);
console.log(matches);
```

**Pattern details**

- `match` - a literal substring
- `(?!100(?!\d))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is `100` substring not followed with a digit (if you want to fail the matches where the number *starts with* `100`, remove the `(?!\d)` lookahead)
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
- `match` - a literal substring

See the [**regex demo online**](https://regex101.com/r/BJdzAR/2).

Comment: The 3 characters are a mix of numbers and letters. Can you rewrite the code to match that? Thanks.

Comment: @frosty If there can be letters, digits or `_` chars, "word" chars, replace `\d+` with `\w+`. You may also use `\S+` if there can be any non-whitespace chars. If there can be any chars, use `.+` or `[^]+`

Comment: Does this also match something that is longer than 3 character with a random mix of numbers and characters? Something like A12M8Y27IW05FA